# Expo simulator not opening on device

Tags: react-native, expo, device, simulator, failed-to-load-viewstate

I have been trying to run expo on my device. The laptop am using cannot meet up with android ide specs so i need something light to develop an android app. So I choose expo with react-native
.When I use tunnel and hotspot my laptop to my phone everything works perfectly i.e.  as long as their is good internet connection.
But am trying to use USB with no internet connection. I get the standard message on the dev tool which ends with 'opening on android device  ' but nothing happens on my mobile device

I have developer debugger activated on the phone
Expo client installed and active
Am using the USB cable that came with the phone
Using an infinix hot 7 pro phone
Adb is active and running on the laptop
I even deactivated all antivirus and firewalls

I cant figure out understand why the phone will not respond even when the system devtool reads ...opening on device.. I get no error message only that it remains at .......opening on device.....

Answer (score 0):

The issue of expo not working without an internet connection was raised on the [expo github](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/101) site a while ago. Currently, the expo-cli does need an internet connection to start.

A user commented that using `yarn start —offline` and selecting `local` worked to solve the problem (when expo start -offline didn't work). Try that!

A [new issue](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/1307) has been created to update the issue in offline expo to avoid having to use the workaround, so this will probably be resolved in a newer release.

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for the info tried 'expo start --offline' but was not successfull